# What happens when python reaches it's soft memory limit?

Tags: python

Processes may have a soft and hard memory limit as described in https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/getrlimit.2.en.html. However, I'm not clear on the result of the soft limit.

Comment: What happened when you tested it?  Please don't ask a question that you can directly test.  Write a program that consumes memory until it fails.

Comment: It's fine to write a question and answer it yourself, but it is strange to write that you're "not clear on the result of the soft limit" when you do actually know what the result is.

Comment: @kaya3 That's because I wasn't clear on what the result was until I did some research and tested it.

Answer (score 2):

Python raises a MemoryError when it reaches the soft memory limit. For example, try running the below:

```
import resource
print('before limit')
print(resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS))
soft_limit = 400000000  # 400 MB
hard_limit = -1  # unlimited
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (soft_limit, hard_limit))
print('after limit')
print(resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS))
print('trying to allocate memory')
x = bytearray(500*1024*1024)  # 500 MB
print('ok')
import time;time.sleep(5)
```

Running this results in a MemoryError Exception. If you change 500 on line 10 to 300 it will work fine.